# SQL Workbench replication

Tags: sql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

На четырех серверах (CentOS 7) установлена репликация по схеме рисунка. При изменении данных и структуры базы данных с командной строки сервера, изменения благополучно разливаются по всем нодам. Однако, если использовать SQL Workbench и синхронизировать изменения с одним из мастеров, то разливаются только данные. Допустим если удалить таблицу, она удалится только на мастере, с которым была синхронизация SQL Workbench'a, на остальных трех серверах таблица останется не тронутой. 
Версия  5.7.29-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
[image: схема]

Comment: Если скопировать SQL-запрос, который Workbench отправляет на сервер и выполнить его через консоль сервера, то изменения разольются по всем нодам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ оказался простым, нужно лишь добавить строчку "USE db_name;" в начало скрипта, 
сгенерированного Workbench.

[image]